# How do I stop bleeding in Boyfriend Dungeon?

Tags: boyfriend-dungeon

In *Boyfriend Dungeon* (PS5), after a date where I

> slept with Sunder

I started bleeding. I finished the story arc, did enough stuff to start a new day, and switched to another weapon, but it won't stop. The game never even acknowledges it's happening, plot-wise. I can't find anything about it googling, so in case it's a bug, I also tried restarting the game.

It's also possible it started when I left a dungeon and not from the date. I only noticed it when I next entered a dungeon. It makes sense it's from the date though because of... You know.

It's making boss fights really difficult. How do I get it to stop?

Answer (score 4):

There's a hat which makes you bleed, and I equipped it right after the date, so I got confused. The description doesn't say anything about bleeding, but if you look at the hat and ask yourself, "could this cause me to take damage over time?" then the answer will become obvious.

Comment: I'm looking through the Wiki for that hat, because it's nicely funny how you described it, but I can't find? https://boyfrienddungeon.fandom.com/wiki/Headgear If you wanna keep it as a spoiler, prefixing a line with >! should make it a spoiler?